# Angular ng-checked if item is in list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two lists of items:
all_todos
my_todos

I want to create a directive that will update the check boxes of the todos if the my todos are updated anywhere else in the application.

```
<tr ng-repeat="todo in all_todos">
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="_.findIndex(my_todos, function(t){return t.id == todo.id;}) > -1"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    {{todo.title}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Angular doesn't like the starting curly brace in the ng-checked.  I want to avoid writing a $scope.watch and placing a property on the array if possible.

Comment: Are your todos identical to all todos?

Comment: Some of my todos may be in all todos, some may not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to create a function in your controller which take the content of your actual ng-checked directive and call it in the ng-checked.

you should have something like that

```
// your controller
angular.module('..').
controller('..', function() {
    $scope.test = function() {
       return  _.findIndex(my_todos, function(t){return t.id == todo.id;}) > -1;
    }
})
```

and in your html

```
<.... ng-checked="test()" />
```

i think the declaration of the function in your directive is the key of your issue